# MySQL master slave replication not working

Tags: mysql, replication

I had MySQL master slave running and working fine but suddenly it stopped. I don't know which commands have been executed but now replication is not working. I am very new to MySQL can anyone help me?

#### Slave

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G

       Slave_IO_State: 
          Master_Host: 192.168.138.220
          Master_User: slaveRoot
          Master_Port: 3306
        Connect_Retry: 60
      Master_Log_File: peer-bin.000937
  Read_Master_Log_Pos: 210
       Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000001
        Relay_Log_Pos: 4
Relay_Master_Log_File: peer-bin.000937
     Slave_IO_Running: No
    Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
      Replicate_Do_DB: 
  Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
   Replicate_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error: 
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 210
          Relay_Log_Space: 264
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File: 
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File: 
       Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
          Master_SSL_Cert: 
        Master_SSL_Cipher: 
           Master_SSL_Key: 
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 1236
            Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log:
'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error: 
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
         Master_Server_Id: 2
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### Master

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
              Master_Host: 173.255.243.207
              Master_User: slave_user
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000937
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 106
           Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.167538
            Relay_Log_Pos: 210
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000937
         Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB: 
      Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
       Replicate_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error: 
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 106
          Relay_Log_Space: 524
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File: 
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File: 
       Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
          Master_SSL_Cert: 
        Master_SSL_Cipher: 
           Master_SSL_Key: 
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 2003
            Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'slave_user@173.255.243.207:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error: 
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
         Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

`SHOW MASTER STATUS\G`

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
              Master_Host: 173.255.243.207
              Master_User: slave_user
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000937
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 106
           Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.167538
            Relay_Log_Pos: 210
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000937
         Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB: 
      Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
       Replicate_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error: 
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 106
          Relay_Log_Space: 524
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File: 
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File: 
       Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
          Master_SSL_Cert: 
        Master_SSL_Cipher: 
           Master_SSL_Key: 
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 2003
            Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'slave_user@173.255.243.207:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error: 
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
         Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

did you check your logs in /var/log/mysqld.log  and in /var/lib/mysql
if you have the general logs enable you should have the last statement that was running

regards

Philippe courtois